# Cliente PHP Soap no muestra los registros

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Cada vez que ejecuto este código para recorrer un método de un web ser service, me aparece este error:

Function ("method") is not a valid method for this service

```
<?php

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 900);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);

$wsdl = 'http://localhost/Integracion.svc?WSDL';
$options = array(
        'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
        'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout'=>15,
        'trace'=>true,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'exceptions'=>true,
    );
try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $data = $soap->method('MiMetodo');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
var_dump($data);
die;

?>
```

¿Dónde puede estar el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method` No es un metodo valido para Soap, lo que puedes hacer es llamar el metodo de las siguientes maneras.

```
$soap->MiMetodo()
```

o

```
$soap->__soapCall('MiMetodo', []);
```